# Getting a duplicate error when trying to setup android studio with appium FindsByClassName

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests, appium

I have just started to learn appium using Android Studio.

After following some earlier posts for the `build.gradle` (app) by setting `multiDexEnabled` true still get the below error when trying to run a sample program.

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     org/openqa/selenium/internal/FindsByClassName.class

I understand with previous posts that there is a duplicate entry but when I try doing an exclude for the  compile ('io.appium:java-client:4.1.2')  an error shows up when the build.gradle is getting synced.Hence I had to include the org/openqa/selenium/internal/ folder.

The commands ./gradlew clean and  ./gradlew dependencies were also tried in terminal.It printed out all the dependencies but I am lost on how to identify the duplicate.

Please find below my module `build.gradle`

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile ('io.appium:java-client:4.1.2'){

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have jar file in your lib folder just remove and compile your dependency then you will be fine .